# inequality in COUNTIF (excel)

Tags: excel, variables, reference, countif, inequality

I am trying to count the cells in a continuous range *if* they are less than or equal to a variable, referenced from another cell. It seems very close to this,

COUNTIF(A4:A20,">=32")

But I want the 32 replaced with a variable, A3. I have not seen an example of that yet. Would be grateful if someone would help me with the formatting. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You just about have it, switch to:

```
=COUNTIF(A4:A20,">="&A3)
```

Comment: Thanks, Chris! Appreciate your help :)